# Call method with void return type in databinding expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

Is it possible to call a void returning method in a databinding expression? (To set a global variable, for example.)
The following doesn't compile:

```
<%# setCurrent(false) %>  // Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'
```

I could change the return type of the method (e.g. have it return a null object), but that would be cheating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't terribly elegant, but gets the job done:

```
<%# new Func<string>(() => { SomeVoidMethod(); return ""; })() %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of databinding is that a value is returned for display.  (hence the error)

Just return an empty string :)

Answer (score 0):

I think putting a semicolon after your statement should make it semantically correct:

```
setCurrent(false);
```

That's not "databinding" per se, but it works.

Comment: I need something that works in markup; not in code-behind or a script block.